# Matching 3 last numbers in a string with regex

Tags: php, regex

**Problem:**

Trying to highlight the last 3 numbers in a string using regular expression.

**Code:**

```
<?php
    show_source('regex.php');

    $string = "
        780155OVERF I000000
        TRANFER DOMESTIC
        000114
        STHLM SE AB
    ";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Regex to match last 3 numbers</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo nl2br(str_replace('/\d{3}(?=[^\d]+$)/g', '<span style="background-color:red;">$1</span>', $string));
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Desired outcome:**

The numbers 114 should have red background color.

Comment: And what shows now?

Comment: `str_replace` doesnt handle REGEX use `preg_replace`

Comment: It's working well https://www.regex101.com/r/yR4uX6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
print nl2br(
        preg_replace('/\d{3}(?=[^\d]+$)/s', 
                     '<span style="background-color:red;">$0</span>', 
                     $string)
           );
```

Answer (score 2):

Main error: `str_replace` doesn't work wit regexes. Use `preg_replace`:

```
$string = "
    780155OVERF I000000
    TRANFER DOMESTIC
    000114
    STHLM SE AB
";

// use `m` modifier as you have multiline string
// `g` modifier is not supported by preg_replace
echo preg_replace("/\d{3}(?=[^\d]+)$/m", '<span>$0</span>', $string);
```